# Python set the root directory to open the file when specifying the relative path in open() method

Tags: python, macos, path

It possible setup env variable like **PYTHON_PATH** but for open() method in macoOS.
For example `open('file.txt')` search `file.txt` in another dir, not same with .py script.
In my case i cant change `open('file.txt')` to absolute path ant move `file.txt` to script dir. I can only to setup environment.

Comment: is that file at a standard relative location to py file where open() is called or the folder where python is executed? Can you change `open('file.txt')` to `open(f'{<relative_path>}/file.txt')`?

Comment: No, I can't change this is not my code. But i need test it locally and the code has many points used relative path to files.

Answer (score 0):

Relative paths are always resolved against the current working directory. You can either change the working directory before running Python (for example, with the `cd` command in your shell) or use `os.chdir` inside your script. There is no environment variable to change the working directory (though this is not impossible; Python simply doesn't recognize any environment variable which it could use to perform an implicit `os.chdir(...)` on startup).

---

Typically, you don't use relative paths in your script, though. You construct an absolute path using a parameter that can be set at runtime.  For example,

```
import argparse, pathlib

p = argparse.ArgumentParser()
p.add_argument("--basepath", type=pathlib.Path, default=pathlib.Path.cwd())
args = p.parse_args()

with open(args.basepath / "file.txt") as f:
    ...
```

(Of course, the user could provide a relative path as the `--basepath` argument. You can either have a runtime check that the value *is* an absolute path, or allow relative paths under the assumption the user will provide a relative path compatible with their current working directory.)